# How do I create an automator to forward mail?

Tags: macos, mail.app, applescript, automator

My parents both have GMAIL accounts. We were wondering if there was a way to forward email so when my dad's account receives email from a certain sender it would be forwarded to my mom's account.

Perhaps using Automator or applescript running on OS X 10.10 to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an easy way to do that right in Gmail. In the settings tab, go to settings and first add a forwarding address under Forwarding and POP/IMAP. Enter the desired forwarding address and confirm it by entering the confirmation code or clicking on the confirmation link. Then go to the Filters and Blocked Addresses tab in settings. On the bottom of the page choose "create a new filter". In the first line enter the email from the certain sender that you would like to forward, then click on "Create filter with this search", which will bring you to the next page. Here check the "Forward it to: choose an address" box, and choose the address.

That should do it. Gmail has great filters for mails 
Hope this is helpful, might not be Automator or applescript, but it's right inside gmail, fast and easy... cheers

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this with Mail rules.

The [gmail method is better](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/223501/5472) in that the forwarding happens when Mail isn't running, but you can set up a rule as follows:

[image]

The rules section is just in Mail preferences. You might try **redirect** instead of forward and see which "mom" prefers. I also added a bonus action of marking the message read - you can explore other options like filing or deleting or leaving it unread if "dad" wants to read these too.